# Why are the box fill on Carlon boxes inconsistent/wrong?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, junction-box

This is a side question to [Box fill calculations for a light switch in a Carlon old work box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/286787/box-fill-calculations-for-a-light-switch-in-a-carlon-old-work-box) because I realized what is written on the Carlon old work boxes is possibly wrong or at least inconsistent.

Left shows a standard, normal box and right the extra deep one (the largest single gang box to be found):

[image]

Right one says 20cu and "8/12", i.e., 8 allowances for AWG12. This makes sense because one allowance for AWG12 is 2.25cu, so 8*2.25=18 ... the the next allowance does not fit any more.

However, the left box says 14cu but ALSO "8/12". If the former is true, I could only fit floor(14/2.25)=6 allowances. Barely enough for anything. If the latter is true, it would fit the same as the big deep box. Doesn't make sense either.

Which one is right and what is the explanation for this inconsistency?

PS: Here are pictures from the interiors:

[image][image]

Comment: Only the blue one is a Carlon. The gray is a Cantex. I expect one of the folks who's more into "Games manufactuers can play with UL listings" will have an answer regarding how Cantex gets to mark for more wire fill than the volume appears to permit, under the "if the listed instructions of the listed device permit, they rule" doctrine, but I can't even find anything on Cantex's web site that admits to the wire fill numbers, which I'd expect they'd be trumpeting in the marketing materials if they have a cheat code for smaller boxes than spec.

Comment: Carlon's incredibly clunky website does indeed list 6 12 AWG for **their** 14 old work, though oddly they also list **9** 12 AWG for the 18 old work, not the 8 we see here. BTW, Cantex makes a 21 CI old work single gang.

Comment: Yeah that makes no sense.  Box fill for 8 #12 wires is 18 CI.

Comment: Interesting that the Cantex box lists `14 CI: 9/14, 8/12, 7/10` while the Carlon lists `20CI: 10/14, 8/12, 8/10`. Cantex allows 1 less #14 or #10, but claims the same #12 despite the 6CI difference...

Comment: Wow that's crazy. I really thought there would be a "simple answer". Seems in doubt I can use the "x/12" markings on the box though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the box UL, CSA or ETL Listed?   You're not allowed to use non-listed boxes except by oversight/approval of the AHJ.  (you can make your own box on a metal brake and the AHJ will look at material and thickness and if it's reasonable they'll be fine with it).

When UL approves equipment, they also approve the labeling and instructions. That's why instructions for dimmers and GFCIs are so obtuse (manufacturers don't want to deviate much from UL's exemplar instructions or previously approved instructions).

As such, if the box has alternate values stamped, *and UL/CSA/ETL has approved the box*, they have validated those numbers and confirmed they satisfy the reason for the rule.

If you see discrepancies in wire count, it's because UL doesn't work like "You asked for ten #14, but honestly we'd let you have thirteen". If you ask for ten, they approve ten. So the manufacturer may have just been cautious about what they were asking for.

Comment: Yes, they are listed (UL and ETL logo visible on the photos) and they are from Home Depot. So just to make sure I understand your answer correctly, the stamped values ("8/12" for both boxes in my question) are "safer" that using the volume and dividing by 2.25?

Comment: @divB the lesser is safer, in some tiny increment by some thousanths of a percent...  but both are approved.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica this is very interesting.  Am I understanding correctly that the reason the Cantex box of 14 cu in is allowed 8 #12s instead of 6 basically boils down to "because they asked ETL for an exception"?  If that's the case, I'd think Carlon would ask for more than 8 for their 20 CI box...and wouldn't they also ask for 8 for *their* 14 CI box so that they can compete with Cantex?   I hear what you're saying about UL approval (not the box fill rule itself) being the key thing...though that does seem to cheapen the box fill rules to a certain degree.

Comment: @susie I wouldn't say so.  UL is accounting for the particular orientation of cables entering that box, since it provides only limited cable entries.  The box fill rules are universal/catch-all rules that work on any box regardless of orientation.

Comment: But the Cantex box is literally identical to the Carlon except the color (that’s also why I didn’t bother to distinguish them in my question).